# Running a process in the background and keeping track of it?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create a GUI to control several streams of audio, to run the stream I simply do `ezstream.exe -c config.xml` and it runs a console window that stays open doing the stream.

What I'm trying to achieve is doing a gui in visual studio with c#.net that has the ability to run the command in the background and keep track if it's still open, the reason I need it this way is because I'm going to have to run about 40-60 streams at once and 60 consoles open at once isn't something I want, what would be the best way to achieve this?

What class can I use that starts the command on the background and fires events if the command crashes or closes? thank you.

Comment: what about a windows service?

Comment: Which GUI? WinForms? WPF? Metr... err. Windows Store Modern?

Comment: I was planning windows forms but my problem isn't really the GUI but the code that the GUI will call

Answer (score 2):

You can use the process class, and subscribe to the `Exited` event.

More on the process class here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Diagnostics.Process.aspx